# Need to get the table row data for which cell is selected using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Have small requirement, I have to select multiple cells in a table. Once we click on submit button we have to show the respective row data of the each cell in alert message.
I tried with below code, im getting cell data, but getting trouble to fetch row data of respective cell. Can any one help me pls,
Here is the sample code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
         $(this).toggleClass('selected'); 
        // alert(table.cell( this ).data());
    } );

    $('#button').click(function() {
        var rowdata = table.rows('.selected').data();
        var cellData = table.cells('.selected').data();
        //console.log(cellData);
        var consoleMsg = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < cellData.length; i++) {
            consoleMsg += cellData[i]+'\n';
            //consoleMsg += rowdata[i]+'\n';
        }
        alert(consoleMsg);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6vxgo1k/10/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution you need. Try this:

```
$(function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    var columnsNames = table.settings()[0].aoColumns.map(function (column) {
        return column.sTitle;
    });

    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });

    $('#button').click(function () {
        var selectedCells = table.cells('.selected');
        var selectedCellsAddresses = selectedCells[0];
        var selectedCellsData = selectedCells.data();
        var selected = [];
        var columnName;

        selectedCellsAddresses.forEach(function (cell, index) {
            if (!selected[cell.row]) {
                selected[cell.row] = {};
            }

            columnName = columnsNames[selectedCellsAddresses[index].column];

            selected[cell.row][columnName] = selectedCellsData[index]
        });

        console.log(selected);
        alert(JSON.stringify(selected));
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t4x34eLx/)

you can do whatever you want with that `selected` variable. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried with ur solution still im getting just cell value only. My actual requirement is if we select multiple cells and click on button, we have to show the row data of the each cell in alert message. Pls suggest me the solution

Comment: Hmm, I think I understand the problem now, let try a thing here

Comment: I found it! check my answer again, and if it works, upvote my answer and mark it as accepted